# Airprint remote webpage (from URL)

Tags: ios, airprint

Is there any way to print a website/web page? I.e. you know the url.

I know there is a way to do it by loading it into a webview and printing it, but this seems a bit OTT.

So is there a `printFromWebpage:(NSURL *)url` style method? Or an easier way to do it?

Many thanks

Comment: Either way the device would be downloading the contents of the page, so there would be no gain in speed/responsiveness to do something like `printFromWebpage:(NSURL *)url` if it even existed (it doesn't). If you don't want to present the web page to your user you could put it into a hidden UIWebView though.

Comment: Its not the download that was the issue, it was the rendering. Whether iOS could print from raw HTML, or whether it would have to render it anyway (in which case a webview would be exactly the same/the only way)